# Biblatex bibliography divided by every keyword

Tags: biblatex

I would like to create some kind of index to my bibfile divided by every keyword in the bibfile. I can make this using

`\nocite(*)` 
`\printbibliography[keyword=SomeKeyword]`

and repeat this for every keyword manually. But I would like to have a dynamic solution. Is it somehow possible to loop this over every keyword in the bibfile? That entries with more than one keyword would turn up multiple times is a desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can hook into `\blx@addkeyword` to collect a list of known keywords that we can then later loop over.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@addkeyword#1#2{%
  \xifinlistcs{\detokenize{#2}}{blx@keywords@\the\c@refsection}
    {}
    {\listcsxadd{blx@keywords@\the\c@refsection}{\detokenize{#2}}}%
  \listcsxadd{blx@keyw@\the\c@refsection @\detokenize{#2}}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\DefineKeywordTitle}[2]{%
  \csdef{keyword@title@#1}{#2}}

\def\blx@bibbykeyword@i#1{%
  \ifcsundef{keyword@title@#1}
    {\printbibliography[keyword=#1, title=#1]}
    {\printbibliography[keyword=#1, title=\csuse{keyword@title@#1}]}}

\newcommand*{\bibbykeyword}{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@keywords@\the\c@refsection}
    {}
    {\forlistcsloop{\blx@bibbykeyword@i}{blx@keywords@\the\c@refsection}}}
\makeatother

\DefineKeywordTitle{dinosaur}{Works about dinosaurs}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
  keywords  = {dinosaur},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  keywords     = {secondary},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibbykeyword
\end{document}
```

[image: Two bibliographies]

---

If you need the keywords sorted, you can try something like

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\def\blx@addkeyword#1#2{%
  \seq_if_exist:cF {g_hchr_keyword_\the\c@refsection _seq}
    {
      \seq_new:c {g_hchr_keyword_\the\c@refsection _seq}
    }
  \seq_if_in:cxF {g_hchr_keyword_\the\c@refsection _seq} {\detokenize{#2}}
    {
      \seq_gput_left:cx {g_hchr_keyword_\the\c@refsection _seq} {\detokenize{#2}}
    }
  \listcsxadd{blx@keyw@\the\c@refsection @\detokenize{#2}}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\DefineKeywordTitle}[2]{%
  \csdef{keyword@title@\detokenize{#1}}{#2}}

\def\blx@bibbykeyword@i#1{%
  \ifcsundef{keyword@title@\detokenize{#1}}
    {\printbibliography[keyword=#1, title=#1]}
    {\printbibliography[keyword=#1, title=\csuse{keyword@title@\detokenize{#1}}]}}

\newcommand*{\bibbykeyword}
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cT {g_hchr_keyword_\the\c@refsection _seq}
      {
        \seq_sort:cn {g_hchr_keyword_\the\c@refsection _seq}
          {
            \str_compare:nNnTF { ##1 } > { ##2 }
              { \sort_return_swapped: }
              { \sort_return_same: }
          }
        
        \seq_map_function:cN {g_hchr_keyword_\the\c@refsection _seq} \blx@bibbykeyword@i
      }
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DefineKeywordTitle{dinosaur}{Works about dinosaurs}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
  keywords  = {dinosaur},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  keywords     = {secondary},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibbykeyword
\end{document}
```

where we used `\str_compare:nNnTF` to sort the strings even though `interface3` says we aren't really supposed to.

Comment: Thank you. This works. However, the keywords are not listed alfabetically. Is that possible?

Comment: There is also a problem with special characters. I have some keywords using norwegian characters. These are now rendered enclosed in curly brackets i.e. {æ} {ø} and {å}. Can they be transformed back to non-brackedet display?

Comment: @HansChr See the edit for the sorting. For the Norwegian characters, I guess it would be best not to use non-ASCII characters as the characters are needed to generate internal names, which may break if you use unsafe characters.

Comment: Thank you for another fast reply! When trying the code for sorting I get an error on: \str_compare:nNnTF { ##1 } > { ##2 }.   Maybe time for me to update my Tex Live?

Comment: As for the Norwegian characters: I will follow your advise.

Comment: Updating Tex Live solved the problem. Sorting working fine now :)  One more thing: I would like to put in a hook with `\newpage` after every keyword listing has finished. But I can't seem to get the hooks to work with the new dynamic code.

Comment: @HansChr Can't you say `\newpage` after the `\printbibliography` calls in `\blx@bibbykeyword@i`?

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused regarding Biber and the norwegian characters. Shouldn't Biber handle everything UTF8?

Comment: The part on norwegian characters is due to a misunderstanding on my part: I use Bibdesk to organize my references and it was set to convert accented characters. Biber was therefore already receiving norwegian characters as {å} etc. With a properly formatted utf8 bib-file. Everything works fine.

Comment: @HansChr Biber can handle Unicode in the input just fine. But (at least until not so long ago with pdfLaTeX) handling of non-ASCII chars on the LaTeX side could be an issue if characters were not just used as normal text (most fields), but also as internal labels (e.g. the entry key or keywords). If you system is modern even that will probably work, but you may want to make sure that the input does not use unnecessary braces etc.. Still, I prefer to be conservative for things that might be used internally to construct macro names and stick to ASCII only.

Comment: That is good advice. The sorting in the answer is case sensitive. I would like to turn that off.  I've tried setting `sortcase=false` when calling `\usepackage{biblatex}`but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @moewe, absolutely amazing! Finally, I can transform my `.bib` file into a management bib file based on multiple categories.